# How to make Paypal Api oauth2 calls from Unity for IOS?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, paypal, oauth-2.0

I get this error trying to get accestoken from Paypal in the IOS deploy while in any other deploy it works, same with postman, it works, any idea on how to solve it?

> HTTP load failed (error code: -999
>   [1:89]) for Task
>   <86785AD5-6827-406B-8A86-4083FB6D8F7D>.<0>
>   WWW Error: The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error
>   -1012.) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType,
>   String, Object)
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType,
>   Object, String, Object[])
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
>   UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType,
>   Object)
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1:Remove(T)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator,
>   IntPtr)

You  can test with this c# code

```
     string clientID = "AYDK0o1OoZ2KwlzKELb7FabVtPBhEFOoHJVxWZlzCKFQIszSqOOpsysSa1KnbZky6-AOtbv8gf5HIZUW";
     string secret = "EBahyWiumNukGFtgW-DE-DXsoYKXbsk8rLAwU_iOaqwmus2Bv8ETmgE_4SFmEU0aurIizeOSZCWmW9Sd";




    Dictionary headers = new Dictionary();

     headers.Add("Accept","application/json");
     headers.Add("Accept-Language","en_US");
     headers.Add("Authorization","Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( clientID + ":" + secret)));

     WWWForm postData = new WWWForm();

     postData.AddField("grant_type", "client_credentials");

     string endpointURL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
     WWW www = new WWW(endpointURL, postData.data,headers);

     Debug.Log("Making call to: " + endpointURL);

     yield return www;
```

Comment: What is your iOS version?

Comment: Tested on 11.2.5, 9.0.2 and 10.3

Comment: Did you test on an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: simulator (iPhone x 11.2.5, iPhone 8 11.2.5, iPhone 5s 11.2.5, iPad pro 11.2.5) Device (iPhone 6s 11.2.5, iPod 5th 9.0.2, iPad Pro 10.3